# Google visualisation errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-visualization

I have google vis datatable and dashboard (control filters, string control, datatable, charts). All element is bind.

So I get from database JSON and send to gViz api to draw table, chart and control.
When I use contols to filter some data and if there is no data for that string then I get error from google visualisation like this:

> One or more participants failed to draw()×
>
> Table has no rows.×

and similar messages. So in my app this is so ugly so is there any way to not showing it?
So if there is no data to not show the error...

I try with CSS option:

```css
#google-visualization-errors-all-3 {
   display:none;
}
```

but its not good solution for me.

Is there any other way, maybe in google visualusation api for dashboard?

**UPDATE:**

```
var slider;
    var ajdi = '';
      function drawVisualization() {
        
       var cssClassNames = {
        'headerRow': 'zaglavlje',
        'tableRow': 'red',
        'oddTableRow': 'red1',
        'selectedTableRow': 'orange-background large-font',
        'hoverTableRow': 'prekoreda',
        'headerCell': 'gold-border',
        'tableCell': 'cell',
        'rowNumberCell': 'underline-blue-font'
    };

        
       var json = $.ajax({
                    url: 'getzadaci.php', // make this url point to the data file
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false
                }).responseText;
                
                // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
        //dodajemo kolonu sa kontrolama
        
        
        
    
        
      
        // Define a category picker control for the Gender column
        var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'control1',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Status',
            'ui': {
            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
              'allowTyping': false,
              'allowMultiple': true,
                          'caption': 'Status'

            }
          }
        });
        
         var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
         'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'control2',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnIndex': 8,
            'ui': {
            'labelStacking': 'horizontal',
              'allowTyping': false,
              'allowMultiple': true,
              'caption': 'Parcela'
            }
          }
        });
         var categoryPicker2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
         'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'control4',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnIndex': 2,
            'ui': {
            'labelStacking': 'horizontal',
              'allowTyping': false,
              'allowMultiple': true,
              'caption': 'Vrsta zadatka'
            }
          }
        });
      
        
        var stringFilter1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'StringFilter',
          'containerId': 'control3',
          'options': {
                      'matchType': 'any',
          'filterColumnIndex': 1,
          'ui': {'labelStacking': 'vertical'}
          }
        });
        
        var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'control5',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Pocetak',
         'ui': {'labelStacking': 'vertical'}
          }
        });
      
        // Define a Pie chart
       
  
      
        // Define a table
        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'Table',
          'containerId': 'chart2',
          'cssClassNames': 'cssClassNames',
          'view': { 'columns': [1,2,12,5,6,8,11] },
          'options': {
        cssClassNames: cssClassNames,
        allowHtml: true
    }
        });
        
       var timeline = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Timeline',
    containerId: 'chart5',
    options: {
    height: '350',
    timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true, 
                backgroundColor: '#ffd' },
    //timeline.barLabelStyle: {color: '#000', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: '13px'},
    //backgroundColor: '#fff',
    colors: ['#55c2a2', '#89d168', '#d3eb87','#8ec63e', '#FFF0BA','#FF542E', '#CFD6DE', '#ADC1D6', '#7297BA']
    //timeline: { rowLabelStyle: {fontName: 'Helvetica', fontSize: 24, color: '#603913' },
               // barLabelStyle: { fontName: 'Garamond', fontSize: 14 } }
    },
    view: {
        // as an example, use columns "Naziv", "Vrsta", "Pocetak", and "Zavrsetak" for the timeline
        columns: [8, 2, 5, 6]
    },
    
});

           var formatter_short = new google.visualization.DateFormat({formatType: 'short'});
           formatter_short.format(data, 5);
           formatter_short.format(data, 6);

        
        new google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
        google.visualization.events.addListener(table.getChart(), 'select', function () {
            var selection = table.getChart().getSelection();
            // iterate over all selected rows
            for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
              //$("#edit").removeClass("edit btn btn-success")
              //$('#edit').addClass('edit btn btn-success');
              ajdi = table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,0);
              $("#vrednostid").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,0));
              $("#naziv1").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,1));
              $("#vrsta_rada1").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,2));
              $("#status1").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,3));
              $("#opis1").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,4));
              $("#usluzno1").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,9));

              var p = new Date(table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,5));
              $("#dp31").datepicker("setDate", p);
              
              var z = new Date(table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,6));
              $("#dp41").datepicker("setDate", z);
              
              //$("#parcele1").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,8));
              //$("#parcele1").select2("val", ["3","19"]);
              var id = table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,10);
              var naziv = table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,8);
              

var idArr = (id.lastIndexOf(',') == (id.length - 1) ? id.substr(0, id.length - 1) : id).split(', ');
var nazivArr = (naziv.lastIndexOf(',') == (naziv.length - 1) ? naziv.substr(0, naziv.length - 1) : naziv).split(', ');
var objHold = [];
for(var j=0,length=idArr.length;j<length;j++)
{
    if(idArr[j] && nazivArr[j]) // make sure both arrays have a value
    objHold.push({id: idArr[j], naziv: nazivArr[j]});
}
$("#parcele1").select2("data", objHold);

            }
        });
    });
        
        

      
        // Create a dashboard
        new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
            // Establish bindings, declaring the both the slider and the category
            // picker will drive both charts.
    bind([categoryPicker, categoryPicker1, categoryPicker2, slider, stringFilter1], [table, timeline]).
            // Draw the entire dashboard.
            draw(data, {'allowHtml':true, 'cssClassNames': 'cssClassNames'});      }
      //table.draw(data, {'allowHtml':true, 'cssClassNames': cssClassNames});      }

function dashboardReady() {
        // The dashboard is ready to accept interaction. Configure the buttons to
        // programmatically affect the dashboard when clicked.
      
        // Change the slider selected range when clicked.
        document.getElementById('rangeButton').onclick = function() {
          slider.setState({'lowValue': 2, 'highValue': 5});
          slider.draw();
        };
      
        // Change the pie chart rendering options when clicked.
        document.getElementById('optionsButton').onclick = function() {
          piechart.setOption('is3D', true);
          piechart.draw();
        };
      }
      


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);// JavaScript Document
```

This is my code, so the important part is .ajac function, so how I can here integrate if row>0 to show charts ???

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using the Google Charts API. To get around it I simply had to check the number of rows that made it through the filters. If it's >= 1, draw the chart. else do whatever you need to; don't draw the chart, display error, etc.

Comment: Edit your post with what you have so far, mainly where you filter the rows and draw the chart.

Comment: I update question with my code, the important part is .ajax where I get JSON data

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a solution to your code in someone else's fork of a GitHub project I've done a bit of work on.  Since I didn't write this I'll link to it in this repository:

[leonardean/angular-google-charts](https://github.com/leonardean/angular-google-chart/blob/49dbaea8a2b8b0cf4a9c7346832467d4012fb7c1/ng-google-chart.js#L196-198)

Here's to code in case this link breaks:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chartWrapper, 'error', function (err) {
                                  google.visualization.errors.removeError(err.id);
                                });
```

If you click the link above it will show you the lines I'm refering to highlighted.  Basically, the author of this code is passing an event listener to the google charts api that listens for the error event, and then in the error handler removes the error.  Not exactly a best practice, but I believe this would still log to console.  If it doesn't you can just log the error to console yourself from the handler, but it does get rid of the ugly red box.

Comment: i will try that solution

Answer (score 1):

This function will get rid of all google chart error messages. Call it in a script tag after your DOM and charts have loaded.

```
// Gets rid of all Google's error messages
function removeGoogleErrors() {
  var id_root = "google-visualization-errors-all-";
    var index = 1;

    while (document.getElementById(id_root + index.toString()) != null) {
      document.getElementById(id_root + index.toString()).style.display = 'none';
      index += 2;
    } 
}
```